# Scala + Play2.0 → Play2.4 SimpleResultについて

Tags: scala, eclipse, playframework

開発環境 
・OSX EI Capitan 10.11
・Scala 2.11.7
・ScalaIDE Build id: 4.2.0-vfinal-2015-09-25T11:10:29Z-Typesafe
・Play 2.4.3

下記サイトを見ながらScala+Playを勉強しているのですが、

Scala＋Play 2.0でWebアプリ開発入門（4）
http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1302/21/news016_2.html

下記コードで

```
def sample1 = Action {  
  SimpleResult(
    header = ResponseHeader(200, Map(CONTENT_TYPE -> "text/html")), 
    body = Enumerator(views.html.index("Sample Controller#sample1"))
  )
}
```

"not found: value SimpleResult"

"type mismatch; found : play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable (which expands to) play.twirl.api.Html required: Array[Byte]"

２つエラーが出ます。

"not found: 〜”の場合、SimpleResult → Resultに変更したらエラーが無くなりました。
”type mismatch; found :　〜”も解決しましたが、

```
def sample1 = Action {
  //SimpleResultが使えなかったのでResultを使う。
  Result(  
    header = ResponseHeader(200, Map(CONTENT_TYPE -> "text/html")),
    body = Enumerator("Sample Controlle#sample1".getBytes)  //.getBytesの型指定が必要
  )
}
```

このままSimpleResultの代わりにResultを使っても良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleResult` は Play 2.3 から `Result` に改名されました。 [Play 2.3 Migration Guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/ja/2.3.x/Migration23#Scala-results) を参照。従って `SimpleResult` の代わりに `Result` を使い続けて問題ありません。